# PHP How to recover from Invalid handle returned from new pdo

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, iis-6

My PHP page uses

```
$db = new PDO ("$type:server=$host;database=$name",$user,$pass);
```

to connect to MS SQLSERVER. and it works like a charm.

But sometimes windows auto installs updates and restarts the DB server.
If PHP tries to connect at that moment it will get an error, and keeps returning another error every time I open a page.

> PHP Fatal error:  Invalid handle returned.

To solve the problem I need to manually kill the PHP process so next time IIS restart it.

If I use

```
;ConnectionPooling=0
```

on connection string I dont get the error, but I preferred not, so I can use connection polling.

**How do I automatically kill the PHP process from inside PHP script?**

I already tried `exec("taskkill /f /pid ".getmypid());` inside `register_shutdown_function` but don't work.
The process is executed but the PHP is not killed.

Comment: Question, in your setup up, you have IIS+PHP and SQL Server on the same machine?

Comment: No they are on different machines.